# Converse of the relative canonical bundle $-K_{X/Z}$ of smooth morphism can not be ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Here is my question which is a classical result:

> Let $f:X\to Z$ be a surjective smooth morphism between smooth projective varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $\dim Z > 0$, then why $-K_{X/Z}$ can not be ample?

In paper [KMM92] [Rational connectedness and boundedness of Fano manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-36/issue-3/Rational-connectedness-and-boundedness-of-Fano-manifolds/10.4310/jdg/1214453188.full) due to János Kollár, Yoichi Miyaoka and Shigefumi Mori, they state this as a corollary (Corollary 2.8) without proof.
In this case $K_X=f^*K_Z+K_{X/Z}$. In [KMM92] they claim that this result can be showed by bend-and-break technique as in Theorem 2.1, but I don't know why? Actually I have no idea how to use bend-and-break technique here???

---

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is $Z$ equal to $Y$?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny Oh I'm sorry. Now I have edited it.

Comment: If $X \cong Y \times Z$ where $Y$ is a Fano variety and $f$ is the projection then $-K_{X/Z}$ is relatively ample.

Comment: @Sasha But $-K_{X/Z}$ need not be absolutely ample on $X$?

Comment: As KMM state, this follows from bend-and-break.  Consider any curve $C$ that is not contained in a fiber, and perform base change by the morphism from $C$ to $Z$.  This reduces to the case that $Z$ is itself a smooth, projective curve that admits a rational section of $f$.  Now use Bend-and-Break to keep breaking off rational curves in fibers and driving "down" the curve class of the "handle" of the comb.  Since there exists some ample divisor class, you cannot do this indefinitely.  Once the handle becomes rigid, the relative anticanonical degree is nonpositive.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your help. But I still not understand, could you give me more detail? Now $Z$ is a smooth projective curve with a (why rational?) section of $f$. Next I don't know how to use Bend-and-Break as we have no "Fano" condition here. So we can not use Frobenius to expand the dimension of the deformation space of maps from curves. By the way, I would appreciate it if you could include it in the answer below.

Comment: Bend-and-break does not only apply to the Fano case.  It applies whenever there is a curve whose anticanonical degree is positive.  Consider the section curve.  If the anticanonical degree is positive, use Bend-and-Break to "break" off a rational curve in a fiber so that the original section curve is algebraically equivalent to the broken-off rational curves union a "handle" that is also a section curve, but now with smaller anticanonical degree.  If the anticanonical degree is still positive for this handle, repeat.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your patient reply. Now I know the main goal of doing Bend-and-Break. Hence finally we get a section curve $C'$ such that $K_X\cdot C'\geq0$. As $K_{X/Z}=K_X-f^*K_Z$, we have $$K_{X/Z}\cdot C'\geq-f^*K_Z\cdot C'\geq-\deg_ZK_Z.$$ Maybe at the first time we need to choose $C$ to be a rational curve?